# How do I enable or re-enable a textbox in a windows forms application, or why is my tbx.Enable = true; code not functional? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, wpf-controls

I have a multiline textbox (`tbxReminderText`) in the following code that is not responding to my including `tbxReminderText.Enabled = true;`, even after trying to include it in multiple other locations.  There is no difference whether or not I have the `Enabled` property set to true or false in the designer properties listing.  Trying to refresh the controls, or anything else that I can think of trying, is not working.  Here's the applicable code:

```
private void EditEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  EntryType.Entries currentTypeEdited = new EntryType.Entries();

  if (mainForm.alarmCLB.SelectedIndex != -1) {
    currentTypeEdited = EntryType.Entries.Alarm;
  } else if (mainForm.reminderCLB.SelectedIndex != -1) {
    currentTypeEdited = EntryType.Entries.Reminder;
  } else {
    currentTypeEdited = EntryType.Entries.Timer;

    //lets change the controls accordingly
    //(no event handler to remove for the existing dtp
    this.Controls.Remove(dtpActiveAt);

    //change existing label
    lblRingAt.Text = "Duration:";

    //set up new control properties

    /* MUCH dynamic insertion of controls removed here for brevity;
     * -+=this is in part of the above if/else branch not used for the
     *    EntryType.Entries.Reminder, which is where my issue lies=+-  */

    this.Controls.Add(nudTmrHrs);
    this.Controls.Add(lblTmrHours);
    this.Controls.Add(nudTmrMin);
    this.Controls.Add(lblTmrMinutes);
    this.Controls.Add(nudTmrSec);
    this.Controls.Add(lblTmrSeconds);
  }

  switch (currentTypeEdited) {
    case EntryType.Entries.Alarm:
      //edit our alarm entry heah
      tbxReminderText.Text = "unavailable";
      tbxReminderText.Enabled = false;
      tbxName.Text =
        HeadsUp.activeAlarms[mainForm.alarmCLB.SelectedIndex].Name;
      dtpActiveAt.Value =
        HeadsUp.activeAlarms[mainForm.alarmCLB.SelectedIndex].ActiveAt;

      break;
    case EntryType.Entries.Timer:
      //edit timer heah
      tbxReminderText.Text = "unavailable";
      tbxReminderText.Enabled = false;
      tbxName.Text =
        HeadsUp.activeTimers[mainForm.timerCLB.SelectedIndex].Name;
      //okay the following isn't a DTP, it's a 3 number field; we're
      //going to have to handle this one differently, hopefully not with
      //a completely different form
      /*dtpActiveAt.Value =
        HeadsUp.activeTimers[mainForm.timerCLB.SelectedIndex].remaining*/

      break;
    case EntryType.Entries.Reminder:
      //reminder tiem
      tbxReminderText.Text =
        HeadsUp.activeReminders[mainForm.reminderCLB.SelectedIndex].Msg;
      tbxReminderText.Enabled = true;
      tbxName.Text =
        HeadsUp.activeReminders[mainForm.reminderCLB.SelectedIndex].Name;
      dtpActiveAt.Value =
        HeadsUp.activeReminders[
          mainForm.reminderCLB.SelectedIndex].ActiveAt;

      break;
  }
}
```

As annotated in the block commenting inline, the problem lies in the code branches selected in the if/else if/else statement activated when `mainForm.reminderCLB.SelectedIndex != -1` (verified that it's taking this branch), and in the switch/case block active when `currentTypeEdited = EntryType.Entries.Reminder`.

I've googled and looked quite a bit on here, but I'm not finding anything similar.  I'm guessing that I've made a stupid error somewhere, and I'm just not seeing it in code review...  Can anybody help in pointing out the mistake that I made, a pointer to applicable resources (I've already looked at Controls.* on MSDN, etc), or let me know what other information I should include for better troubleshooting?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in debugger on `tbxReminderText.Enabled = true;` to make sure it's hit when intended?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the parent container has property Enabled set to false. When the parent container is not enabled children will not be enabled as well even if you try to set them to true.

**Edit**

try examining `tbxReminderText.Parent.Enabled` property value in the watch window and check its value before setting `tbxReminderText.Enabled` to true.